# Rails association through a SHA1 rather than id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, sha1

I'm trying to link two tables on a SHA1 rather than doing a find for the SHA1 across tables, and linking the via id.

My models are

```
class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :dataset_hash
end

class DatasetHash < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :datasets
end
```

I tried linking using

```
  has_many :datasets, :finder_sql => 'Select datasets.* FROM datasets LEFT JOIN dataset_hashes ON datasets.dataset_hash=dataset_hashes.hash WHERE dataset_hashes.hash=#{dataset.dataset_hash}'
```

but I just get an error of

DatasetHash(#...) expected, got String(#...)

Comment: Have you had any luck using the `:foreign_key` option instead?

Comment: from my understanding, foreign_key only lets me define a one-way relationship (unless I am not understanding it correctly), so with foreign_key I could say first_table.id maps to second_table.other_field by belongs_to first_table, :foreign_key => other_field. I don't see how I can define that across two non-id fields

Comment: It may be more convenient in your case to use a non-integer primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:foreign_key` and `:primary_key` available in [belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) and [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

```
class Dataset < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :dataset_hash, :primary_key => "dataset_hash", :foreign_key => "hash"
end

class DatasetHash < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :datasets, :primary_key => "hash", :foreign_key => "dataset_hash"
end
```